# ASP.Net has very high server time

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a 32-bit asp.net application running in IIS 7.5. I am having an issue with the pages.

**Mentioned the issue below.**

1. Open a page. Hit the database through some action in the page.
2. Open another page in another tab. Now, the second page doesn't respond till the first page responds. The second page has no database hits in page load. It's just plain HTML.

   This happens with all the pages in the application. I am not sure if it is because of IIS or my application.

Comment: Are you performing ajax requests on the first page that hits up the database? Does the first page properly finish loading?

Comment: The first page loads properly. No ajax requests on the first page, infact I perform very few ajax requests in the entire website.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sessions enabled? If yes, all requests will be run serially. If you can, try to avoid using sessions or only enable it where you need it.

Comment: I have Max worker process set to 1 in my app pool. Would that affect this ?

Comment: @user3920019 Yes, that might also be the reason.

Comment: @user3920019 - don't touch the Max Worker Process setting, leave it at 1

Comment: Well, I do set it in my config file. This is my piece of code

<sessionState mode="InProc"/>